# Why doesn't this proof change indices?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

In [this pdf](http://www.cjcaesar.ch/fribourg/docfrib/rg/christoffel.pdf), in the second line of the proof, $\sigma$ was plugged in where it appears as
$$\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial  y^{\rho'}}$$
Meanwhile in converting the coordinates of $g^{\mu'\rho'}$, this was placed:
$$\frac{\partial y^{\rho'}}{\partial  x^\rho}$$
My question is, why didn't we use this:
$$\frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial  y^{\rho'}}$$
instead of
$$\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial  y^{\rho'}}$$

Comment: I edited your title to try to get at what you're asking more directly, but if you can think of a better title, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of future link rot.

Comment: @Qmechanic oh my apologies, is the link broken?

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics: No, but it might be in the future. Also, please make your question a bit clearer. The linked proof is a mess of indices and hard to read; I can't find $\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial y^{\rho '}}$ anywhere. I guess you are probably referring to $J^\sigma_{\rho '}$, but you should add more detail anyway (unless someone more skilled at deciphering indices than I can answer).